# LoRaWan - is it possible to track athletes?

Tags: gps, iot, lora, lorawan

For a long time I have been looking at LoRaWan technology for solving the problem of sports traking (in particular for orienteering), but the information is very fragmented and contradictory. I would like to know how difficult it is to implement the scheme described below. Links to examples of hardware, suitable articles on the topic, and in general any materials for thought are welcome.

**Given:**
On a relief forest terrain, 5 * 5 kilometers for example, control points are located, athletes run along it and visit these points. The terrain can be complicated by rocks, buildings, etc.

**A task:**
Record the athlete's visit to the checkpoint. A visit is successful, if the athlete is at a distance of 1-5 meters from the point. Give feedback to the athlete (light and sound signal that he has succeed, and he can proceed to the next point). Transmit athlete ID and point visited ID to base station. Ideally, transmit the position of the athlete (GPS tracking).

**Requiremenets (in order of decreasing priority):**

1. Lossless communication, signal loss is unacceptable.
2. The price of a device wearable by an athlete should not exceed 40 eur, ideally not more than 10 eur. (up to 5 eur will generally be an absolute success). The price of the check point equipment should not exceed 50 eur. (check point must be weatherproof).
3. If possible, not too expensive base station. "Outdoor" station from *The Things Network* worth ~ 450 eur. looks expensive. The station can be placed in a warm place (in a car, for example), and only an antenna outside.
4. Ease of deployment and programming. Ideally, just turn everything on and collect data in CSV (for example) to process later. Slightly less - the ability to write a handler in any high-level language (python, C#, etc).
5. The possibility of organizing control points in the mesh network, in case one of them is outside the range of reliable reception, or the ability to easily increase the range by installing additional relay nodes.

Thanks!

Comment: As a device you might want to look at the TTGO T-Beam (about $25). It has Lora, GPS, and BLE. You could use BLE for detecting checkpoint visits. When reaching a checkpoint you could also transmit the athlete's track, so it wouldn't be fully live, but you could still get it during the race. One problem would be the amount of data to transmit, as Lora has restricted duty cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. But LoRaWAN may not be the best fit for this task.

**Localization**

First of all it is not possible to localize nodes with the required accuracy with LoRaWAN alone. For that you would need to use something else, possibly Bluetooth beacons. There is a [whitepaper](https://lora-alliance.org/resource-hub/lora-alliance-geolocation-whitepaper) on localization with LoRaWAN based on RSSI and RX times, but that requires at least three gateways and gives you an accuracy of maybe 100m with precise RX times which not all gateways can record with the required precision (generally only if a GPS receiver is also present and currently connected).

**Latency**

A communication round trip with LoRaWAN for class A devices takes between 1 and 5 seconds, because there is a fixed delay between the uplink and the downlink RX windows. This may be less than ideal for the athlete feedback (I am not familiar with Orienteering, but I would expect athletes not to linger at the checkpoints). On the other hand battery life would likely not be a concern for this application, so it may be possible to switch to class C where downlinks are always possible. Still it will take time for all the cloud based processing and the downlink to the gateway which will likely connect via GSM/3G/LTE. Also there is always some packet loss and retransmissions take time.

In the EU there is also a duty cycle restriction on the most common ISM bands around 868MHz, so larger packets may take even longer to retransmit, depending on the implementation (better implementation keep track of the duty cycle over an hour, so infrequent short "bursts" of communication are possible).

So in practice your device should decide the feedback to athletes locally, without waiting for a server connection. This also means that the beacon and/or the device would have to record the visits reliably.

**Reliability**

Lossless communication is not offered out of the box in the LoRaMAC implementations I know. You would have to implement a packet queue on the devices.

**No Mesh**

There is no built-in mesh in LoRAWAN (you can implement or adapt one yourself of course, but that goes against "ease-of-development"), but you can easily add more gateways, it is sufficient for one of them to receive the uplink packets. In a forest that is interesting for Orienteering I would expect you to need multiple gateways anyway for speedy reception. LoRaWAN works great with line of sight, but obstacles reduce the range and it will not penetrate hills. If you just want the data at the end, it would work well, but then you do not need LoRAWAN at all, so it is a tradeoff between cost and speed of data transmission once you have implemented a reliable packet queue.